# How to add multiple many to many data in django shell

Tags: python, django, django-shell

I have a player instance who played three leagues. in the player model class, I set many to many fields with league class.

Now I want to add all 3 leagues to the player instance in Django shell.

```
class League(models.Model):
        league = models.CharField(max_length=20)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.league

    class Player(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        league_played = models.ManyToManyField(League, default='Unknown')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something along the following lines should work. Use the field's `add` method as outlined in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships):

```
p = Player.objects.get(name=whatever)
p.league_played.add(*League.objects.filter(league__in=['league_name1', 'ln2', 'ln3']))
```

For a better django shell, I can recommend you  `django-extension`'s [shell_plus](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html) which has some cool features like code completion or auto imports of all your models.